# Would a Japanese person say "Yay, no school!" or "Yay, no classes!"?

Tags: word-choice, culture

Quick question about word choice, but do the Japanese more often refer to school sessions as "school" like most in America, or "classes" like some parts of Europe?

Also what words would be used most often to describe a school session?
And lastly, what exactly would a child say that's equivalent to "Yay, no school!"?

Comment: Please let that not be クラス let that not be クラス... :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> "do the Japanese more often refer to school sessions as "school" like most in America, or "classes" like some parts of Europe?"

It would definitely be 「学校{がっこう}」 unless your focus is on individual classess for some reason, in which case,  「授業{じゅぎょう}」 may be used.

> "what words would be used most often to describe a school session? "

It would be 「授業{じゅぎょう}」 nearly 100% of the time in grades 1 through 12.

In universities, 「講義{こうぎ}」 is also widely used.  It means "lecture" as far as nuance.

> "And lastly, what exactly would a child say that's equivalent to "Yay, no school!"?"

「やった～、（明日{あした}は）学校[休]{やす}み！」, 「（今日{きょう}/明日）学校なし！」, etc. should be most common at least around Tokyo and Nagoya.